# The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm getting this error message every time I try to submit the form:

> The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form

My form code is this:

```
<form novalidate action="{{path('signup_index')}}" method="post" {{form_enctype(form)}} role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.email, 'Email', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-md-1 control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'col-md-2'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.nickname, 'Nickname', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-md-1 control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.nickname, {'attr':{'class': 'col-md-2'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.nickname, {'attr': {'class': 'col-md-3'}}) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.password, 'password', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-md-1 control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.password, {'attr': {'class': 'col-md-2'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.password, {'attr': {'class': 'col-md-3'}}) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.password_repeat, 'Repeat password', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-md-1 control-label'}}) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.password_repeat, {'attr':{'class': 'col-md-2'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.password_repeat, {'attr': {'class': 'col-md-3'}}) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-1 control-label">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Why did you protect this?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You need to add the `_token` in your form i.e

```
{{ form_row(form._token) }}
```

As of now your form is missing the CSRF token field. If you use the twig form functions to render your form like `form(form)` this will automatically render the CSRF token field for you, but your code shows you are rendering your form with raw HTML like `<form></form>`, so you have to manually render the field.

Or, simply add `{{ form_rest(form) }}` before the closing tag of the form.

> According to docs
>
> This renders all fields that have not yet been rendered for the given
> form. It's a good idea to always have this somewhere inside your form
> as it'll render hidden fields for you and make any fields you forgot
> to render more obvious (since it'll render the field for you).

[**form_rest(view, variables)**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-rest-view-variables)

Comment: {{ form_rest(form) }} was best in my case. Thanks, +1

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid I have a from with files and rendering it via symfony form component. getting the token in twig and getting the token value in controller as well but, getting same error always.

Comment: Thanks, in my case, i had `{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}`  that I'd set before for some tests. Now I changed it to normal `{{ form_end(form) }}` and it worked.

Comment: If you get to this post, keep in mind that the documentation does not include this information. I have created 1 PR to add it but I don't know what else I can do to help other people, greetings. https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/16321

Answer (score 41):

Also you can see this error message when your form has a lot of elements.

This option in php.ini cause of problem

```
; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
 max_input_vars = 1000
```

Problem is that _token field misses PUT (GET) request, so you have to increase value.

Also, it concerns a big files. Increasing the

```
upload_max_filesize
```

option will solve problem.

Comment: In my case it was post_max_size + upload_max_filesize

Comment: I only had the issue when submitting a form with lots of elements.  And **setting max_input_vars to a larger number fixed it for me** too . It makes sense when you think about it - the CSRF token is the last form element rendered and sent up, usually. And when you have too many elements **"further input variables are truncated from the request."**.  So the CSRF token is just missing by the time it gets to Symfony. (source: http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars).

Comment: after 4 hours of debugging this csrf error, I found the answer here. My form was too big and not sending the csrf. Thanks

Comment: In my case, the form itself did not look extremely big, but there was a relations field with 100s of relations.

Answer (score 9):

This happens because forms by default contain CSRF protection, which is not necessary in some cases.

You can disable this CSRF protection in your form class in `getDefaultOptions` method like this:

```
// Other methods omitted

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'csrf_protection' => false,
        // Rest of options omitted
    );
}
```

If you don't want to disable CSRF protection, then you need to render the CSRF protecion field in your form. It can be done by using `{{ form_rest(form) }}` in your view file, like this:

```
<form novalidate action="{{path('signup_index')}}" method="post" {{form_enctype(form)}} role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <!-- Code omitted -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-1 control-label">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </div>

    </div>
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
</form>
```

`{{ form_rest(form) }}` renders all fields which you haven't entered manually.

Comment: "Not neccessary" might be fine, but is there any good reason to not protect each and every form?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes, if you build a stateless api. You can still use symfony forms for validation and not need CSRF protection https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166724/should-i-use-csrf-protection-on-rest-api-endpoints

Answer (score 7):

Before your `</form>` tag put:

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

It will automatically insert other important (hidden) inputs.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with a weird behavior: clearing the browser cache didn't fix it but clearing the cookies (that is, the PHP session ID cookie) did solve the issue.

This has to be done *after* you have checked all other answers, including verifying you *do* have the token in a hidden form input field.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to others' suggestions you can get CSRF token errors if your session storage is not working.

In a recent case a colleague of mine changed 'session_prefix' to a value that had a space in it.

```
session_prefix: 'My Website'
```

This broke session storage, which in turn meant my form could not obtain the CSRF token from the session.

Comment: A related gotcha is invalidating the session in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you have converted your form from plain HTML to twig, be sure you didn't miss deleting a closing `</form>` tag. Silly mistake, but as I discovered it's a possible cause for this problem.

When I got this error, I couldn't figure it out at first. I'm using `form_start()` and `form_end()` to generate the form, so I *shouldn't have to explicitly add the token* with `form_row(form._token)`, or use `form_rest()` to get it. [It should have already been added automatically by `form_end()`.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-end-view-variables)

The problem was, the view I was working with was one that I had converted from plain HTML to twig, and I had missed deleting the closing `</form>` tag, so instead of :

```
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I had:

```
</form>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

That actually seems like something that might throw an error, but apparently it doesn't, so when `form_end()` outputs `form_rest()`, the form is already closed. The actual generated page source of the form was like this:

```
<form>
    <!-- all my form fields... -->
</form>
<input type="hidden" id="item__token" name="item[_token]" value="SQAOs1xIAL8REI0evGMjOsatLbo6uDzqBjVFfyD0PE4" />
</form>
```

Obviously the solution is to delete the extra closing tag and maybe drink some more coffee.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error recently. Turns out that my cookie settings were incorrect in config.yml. Adding the `cookie_path` and `cookie_domain` settings to `framework.session` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same issue recently, and my case was something that's not mentioned here yet:

The problem was I was testing it on `localhost` domain. I'm not sure why exactly was this an issue, but it started to work after I added a host name alias for `localhost` into `/etc/hosts` like this:

```
127.0.0.1        foobar
```

There's probably something wrong with the session while using Apache and `localhost` as a domain. If anyone can elaborate in the comments I'd be happy to edit this answer to include more details.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use form_row or form_rest and just want to access value of the _token in your twig template. Use the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form[_token]" value="{{ form._token.vars.value }}" />
```

Comment: If you do this, make sure to always call {% do form._token.setRendered %} otherwise you may get two token input fields if you have a form_rest call somewhere

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got a trouble with the maxSize annotation in the entity, so I increased it from 2048 to 20048.

```
 /**
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "20048k",
 *     mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid PDF"
 * )
 */
private $file;
```

hope this answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. After ensuring the token field was actually rendered (see accepted answer) I checked my cookies.
There were 2(!) cookies for the domain in my Chrome browser, apparently because I was running the application on the same domain as another app, but with a different port (i.e. mydomain.com set the original cookie while the buggy app was running on mydomain.com:123)
Now apparently Chrome sent the wrong cookie so the CSRF protection was unable to link the token to the correct session.

Fix: clear all the cookies for the domain in question, make sure you don't run multiple applications on the same domain with differing ports.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but in my case the problem was that my application was using multiple first-level domains, while the cookie was using one. Removing `cookie_domain: ".%domain%"` from `framework.session` in the `config.yml` caused cookies to default to whatever domain the form was on, and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that CSRF token is stored in the session, so this problem can also occur due to invalid session handling. If you're working on the localhost, check e.g. if session cookie domain is set correctly (in PHP it should be empty when on localhost).

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this error when opening many pages of the same website in tabs. Some of the tabs would fail to submit.

I am assuming the reason is that each request reads the session at the start of the page load and then writes it again after the page has finished loading, overwriting the results of other page loads.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be an issue when using bootstrap unless you are rendering the form by {{ form(form)}}. In addition, the issues seems to only occur on input type="hidden". If you inspect the page the with the form, you'll find that the hidden input is not part of the markup at all or it's being rendered but not submitted for some reason. As suggested above, adding {{form_rest(form)}} or wrapping the input like below should do the trick.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
</div>
```