# Csrf token is invalid

Tags: symfony, csrf, fosuserbundle, registration, symfony3.x

i've been having the Csrf token is invalid I tried to add the             `{{ form_end(form) }}`
 or remove token from `{{ form_widget(form._token) }}` but it doens't work please help me fix this problem 
here'is my registration content file

```
    {% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

<div class="login-container bg-white">
    <div class="p-l-50 m-l-20 p-r-50 m-r-20 p-t-50 m-t-30 sm-p-l-15 sm-p-r-15 sm-p-t-40">
        <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="logo" data-src="assets/img/logo.png"
             data-src-retina="assets/img/logo_2x.png" width="78" height="22">
        <p class="p-t-35">Sign into your pages account</p>

        <form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">

            <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                <label>Username</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    {{ form_widget(form.username,{'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control' , 'placeholder' : 'E-mail'}}) }}
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                <label>E-mail</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    {{ form_widget(form.email,{'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control' , 'placeholder' : 'E-mail'}}) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                <label>Passowrd</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first,{'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control' , 'placeholder' : 'Mot de passe'}}) }}
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                <label>Passowrd</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second,{'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control' , 'placeholder' : 'Confirmez mot de passe'}}) }}
                </div>
            </div>



            {{ form_rest(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
            <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}"class="btn btn-primary btn-cons m-t-10" />
        </form>

        <div class="pull-bottom sm-pull-bottom">
            <div class="m-b-30 p-r-80 sm-m-t-20 sm-p-r-15 sm-p-b-20 clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 no-padding">
                    <img alt="" class="m-t-5" data-src="assets/img/demo/pages_icon.png"
                         data-src-retina="assets/img/demo/pages_icon_2x.png" height="60"
                         src="assets/img/demo/pages_icon.png" width="60">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9 no-padding m-t-10">
                    <p>
                        <small>
                            Create a pages account. If you have a facebook account, log into it for this
                            process. Sign in with <a href="#" class="text-info">Facebook</a> or <a href="#"
                                                                                                   class="text-info">Google</a>
                        </small>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: the error]

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace FOS\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

/**
 * Controller managing the registration.
 *
 * @author Thibault Duplessis <thibault.duplessis@gmail.com>
 * @author Christophe Coevoet <stof@notk.org>
 */
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $formFactory FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

                $userManager->updateUser($user);

                if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                    $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
                }

                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

                return $response;
            }

            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

            if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                return $response;
            }
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Tell the user to check their email provider.
     */
    public function checkEmailAction()
    {
        $email = $this->get('session')->get('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');

        if (empty($email)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_register'));
        }

        $this->get('session')->remove('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');
        $user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByEmail($email);

        if (null === $user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with email "%s" does not exist', $email));
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/check_email.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Receive the confirmation token from user email provider, login the user.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param string  $token
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function confirmAction(Request $request, $token)
    {
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        $user = $userManager->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);

        if (null === $user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with confirmation token "%s" does not exist', $token));
        }

        /** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

        $user->setConfirmationToken(null);
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM, $event);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Tell the user his account is now confirmed.
     */
    public function confirmedAction()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/confirmed.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'targetUrl' => $this->getTargetUrlFromSession(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function getTargetUrlFromSession()
    {
        $key = sprintf('_security.%s.target_path', $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getProviderKey());

        if ($this->get('session')->has($key)) {
            return $this->get('session')->get($key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any log of the error to share?

Comment: @Signo i added a picture of the error

Comment: You don't have to do `{{ form_widget(form._token) }}` as its already rendered in `{{ form_rest(form) }}`. Can you show us how do you submit your form in your controller?

Comment: i edited in the descrption

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455780/the-csrf-token-is-invalid-please-try-to-resubmit-the-form