# Invalid CSFR token error on registration when moved to Production server

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I moved my symfony project to a production environment on a new server. Everything seems to have gone okay, composer installed fine, etc.  However, the registration form, we're using FOSUSERBUNDLE, now returns the error "**The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.**".  Resubmitting the form just returns the same error. I had no issues with this on the development server.

I am overriding the FOSUERBUNDLE registration form and .twig page template but the changes are minimal other than adding some form fields.

I verified that the sessions are being created in var/sessions/prod.  The registration form has the

```
<input type="hidden" id="fos_user_registration_form__token" name="fos_user_registration_form[_token]" value="U5ONtHIcHgIpmj9yNWOl13r91QGzgbqu4y3ypk3rq34" />
```

field in it but I also tried forcing the _csrf_token field  in the form but that did not help.

From security.yml:

```
    firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: app_startpage
            always_use_default_target_path: true
        logout:
            handlers: [logout_listener]
        anonymous:    ~
        switch_user: ~
        remember_me:
           secret: '%secret%'
```

Is there any other code of relevance that I can show?

**Solved**:  I finally found a thread here with a solution that worked. We are operating this site with sub-domains (each "business" has their own sub-domain) and I had added code so that cookies were shared across sub-domains, cookie_domain: '.%base_url%'. Removing that fixed the issue with the invalid csrf token. The original post: stackoverflow.com/a/49481416/6759549

Comment: Usually this problem occurs when you have file permissions issues or wrong PHP configuration.
Make sure the directory where PHP saves the sessions is writeable by your apache/php/nginx user

Comment: The sessions directories appear to have the correct permissions and sessions are being created in /var/sessions/prod.

Do you know specifically what PHP configuration might be causing the issue?

Comment: I finally found a thread here with a solution that worked.  We are operating this site with sub-domains (each "business" has their own sub-domain) and I had added code so that cookies were shared across sub-domains, cookie_domain: 
 '.%base_url%'.   Removing that fixed the issue with the invalid csrf token.

The original post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481416/6759549